# Chrome 62: sendkeys seems to be causing chrome://settings/help to open

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

An automated Selenium-webdriver / node.js test that I have used daily for years (with regular modifications) seems to be acting up in Chrome 62 on the Mac (Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Every time sendkeys is used to fill out an input the chrome://settings/help tab opens up. I'm not seeing similar behavior in Firefox, and it began after Chrome auto-updated this afternoon.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior? 
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm on the latest Chrome and not seeing this issue. What Chromedriver are you using? I'm still on 2.32, might be an issue with 2.33?

Comment: If you post that "Chromedriver 2.33 solves this issue. Fix works both for Nightwatch, too." I will upvote it.

Comment: I have also updated my chrome and not able to launch it with selenium script. I tried it without testng and its working fine but not when m trying to run testng test.

Comment: @user28732  What error do you get?

Comment: Awesome .. updating chromedriver to 2.33 solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Chromedriver 2.33 solves this issue. Fix works both for Nightwatch, too.

Most issues I come across like this, changing the Chromedriver even temporarily can sort it.